# Expected a truncated byte

Tags: elixir

When I pass 2 size of bits as follow:

```
iex(11)> <<2 :: size(2)>>
```

I've got as output in the iex(I determine the size of the bit)

```
<<2::size(2)>>
```

But when I write following in the iex

```
iex(12)> <<3 :: size(2)>>
```

I've got

```
<<3::size(2)>>
```

but expected

```
<<1::size(2)>>
```

And by 4

```
iex(13)> <<4 :: size(2)>>
<<0::size(2)>>
```

I've got zero and for it is right, but with 3 why I've got 3 instead 1?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`size(2)` means 2 bits, which can hold 4 (2^2) values: 0, 1, 2 or 3.

It seems like you were looking to store 1 bit if you expected 3 to become 1. For that, use `size(1)`:

```
iex> <<3::size(1)>>
<<1::size(1)>>
```